# UX.SE logo is almost impossible to see in SE Data Explorer

Tags: bug, design, usability

This seems to have been addressed in different questions about the mobile version, profile pages, and chat, but the logo is white on white in the [SE Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/user%20experience/query/4038/find-interesting-unanswered-questions).

[image: It's quite hard to see]

Comment: It's like that in multiple places :/ it halso happens if you onebox the site logo. It's because the logo itself doesn't have a background color...and it's never been corrected

Comment: What gets me is the Home tab has the same logo with a blue background. I figured this would/should be a smaller version of that.

Comment: It really should be IMO, it'd work in pretty much all cases if it had the background as part of the image.

Comment: This isn't the only place the logo is hard to detect. In fact [it has been mentioned before](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/530/ux-stackexchange-logo-is-hard-to-see-in-the-se-profile-pages-accounts-tab) in the past (and on other instances has been [addressed](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/751/ux-stack-exchange-logo-is-extremely-hard-to-see-in-the-mobile-version-header) too)